# How to redirect subdomain www to non-www on Nuxt.js

Tags: redirect, nuxt.js, subdomain

I'm building a Nuxt.js website and I want to redirect all www inbound to the naked domain (non-www).

For example, redirect `www.website.com` --> `website.com`

I found this package: [k-domains](https://www.npmjs.com/package/k-domains) which solves the problem. But it seems an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a library to solve this. Actually, it's not even a Nuxt.js problem.

**You should setup this 'redirection rule' on your hosting service.** Most hosting service allows a very easy redirection setup.

But if you want some more complex redirection rule (like `demo.website.com` --> `website.com/demo`), than you should consider using k-domains.